# Error File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead. Laravel Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un modal en donde quiero que el usuario suba un logo, pero Vuejs no me deja poner un input de tipo file.. me sale este error `<input v-model="eq_foto" type="file">:
File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead.`

Mire varios post sobre la directa `v-on:change` y no me queda claro como usarlo.

este es mi form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Ingrese el nombre del Equipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;" v-model="eq_nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del equipo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Ingrese la descripcion del Equipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;" v-model="eq_descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la descripcion del equipo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Categoría</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select class="form-control" v-model="id_categoria">
                                <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                                <option v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id" :value="categoria.id" v-text="categoria.cat_nombre">
                                </option>
                            </select>                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Ingrese el logo del Equipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="file" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;" v-model="eq_foto" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el logo del equipo" @change="previewFiles" multiple ref="myFiles" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-show="errorEquipo" class="form-group row div-error">
                        <div class="text-center text-error">
                            <div v-for="error in errorMostrarMsjEquipo" :key="error" v-text="error">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Mas arriba se puede ver el input de tipo file que me esta creando problemas..

esta es mi data

```
data() {
        return {
            // declaracion de variables
            eq_id: '',
            eq_nombre: '',
            eq_descripcion: '',
            id_categoria: '',
            eq_foto: '',
            arrayEquipo: [],
            modal: 0,
            tituloModal: '',
            // la variable tipoAccion sirve para saber si se quiere actualizar o registrar un nuevo registro
            tipoAccion: 0,
            errorEquipo: 0,
            errorMostrarMsjEquipo: [],
            pagination: {
                'total': 0,
                'current_page': 0,
                'per_page': 0,
                'last_page': 0,
                'from': 0,
                'to': 0,
            },
            offset: 3,
            campo: 'eq_nombre',
            buscar: '',
            arrayCategoria: [],

            files: [],
        }
    },
```

y esto es mis methods

```
methods : {
        previewFiles() {
            this.files = this.$refs.myFiles.files
          },
        listarEquipo(page, buscar, campo) {
            let me = this;
            var url = '/equipo?page=' + page + '&buscar=' + buscar + '&campo=' + campo;
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                // si todo sale bien;
                var respuesta = response.data;
                me.arrayEquipo = respuesta.equipos.data;
                me.pagination = respuesta.pagination;

              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                // si todo sale mal XD
                console.log(error);
              });
        },
        selectCategoria(){
            let me=this;
            var url= '/categoria/selectCategoria';
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                //console.log(response);
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.arrayCategoria = respuesta.categorias;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        cambiarPagina(page, buscar, campo) {
            let me = this;
            // actualiza pagina actual
            me.pagination.current_page = page;
            // envia la peticion para visualizar la data de esa pagina
            me.listarEquipo(page, buscar, campo);
        },
        registrarEquipo() {
            if(this.validarEquipo()) {
                return;
            }
            let me = this;
            axios.post('/equipo/registrar', {
                // junto a la url pasamos los parametros que se van a guardar
                'eq_nombre' : this.eq_nombre,
                'eq_descripcion' : this.eq_descripcion,
                'id_categoria': this.id_categoria,
                'eq_foto': this.eq_foto

            }).then(function (response) {
                // si todo sale bien
                me.cerrarModal();
                // llama a listar fecha y le pasamos la pagina, palabra a buscar y campo
                me.listarEquipo(1, '', 'eq_nombre');


            }).catch(function (error) {
                // si todo sale mal XD;
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        actualizarEquipo() {
            if(this.validarEquipo()) {
                return;
            }
            let me = this;
            axios.put('/equipo/actualizar', {
                // junto a la url pasamos los parametros que se van a guardar
                'eq_nombre' : this.eq_nombre,
                'id': this.eq_id,
                'eq_descripcion' : this.eq_descripcion,
                'id_categoria': this.id_categoria,
                'eq_foto': this.eq_foto


            }).then(function (response) {
                // si todo sale bien
                me.cerrarModal();
                me.listarEquipo(1, '', 'eq_nombre');

            }).catch(function (error) {
                // si todo sale mal XD;
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        desactivarEquipo(id) {
            const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
              cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
              buttonsStyling: false,
            })

            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
              title: 'Desea descativar este equipo ?',
              // text: "Si descativa esta categoria los equipos con esta categoria se veran afectados!",
              type: 'warning',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: 'Si, descativar!',
              cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
              reverseButtons: true
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                let me = this;
                axios.put('/equipo/desactivar', {
                    // junto a la url pasamos los parametros que se van a guardar
                    'id': id

                }).then(function (response) {
                    // si todo sale bien
                    me.listarEquipo(1, '', 'eq_nombre');
                    // swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                    //   'Descativado!',
                    //   'La fecha ha sido descativado.',
                    //   'success'
                    // )

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // si todo sale mal XD;
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
              } else if (
                // Read more about handling dismissals
                result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
              ) {
              }
            })
        },
        activarEquipo(id) {
            const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
              cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
              buttonsStyling: false,
            })

            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
              title: 'Desea activar este equipo ?',
              // text: "Si activa esta categoria los partidos con esta categoria se veran afectados!",
              type: 'info',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: 'Si, activar!',
              cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
              reverseButtons: true
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                let me = this;
                axios.put('/equipo/activar', {
                    // junto a la url pasamos los parametros que se van a guardar
                    'id': id

                }).then(function (response) {
                    // si todo sale bien
                    me.listarEquipo(1, '', 'eq_nombre');
                        // swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                        //   'Activado!',
                        //   'La fecha ha sido activada.',
                        //   'success'
                        // )

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // si todo sale mal XD;
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
              } else if (
                // Read more about handling dismissals
                result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
              ) {
              }
            })
        },
        validarEquipo() {
            // funcion para comprobar que el campo fe_nombre no este vacio
            this.errorEquipo = 0;
            this.errorMostrarMsjEquipo = [];

            if(!this.eq_nombre)this.errorMostrarMsjEquipo.push('El nombre del equipo no puede estar vacio!');

            if (this.errorMostrarMsjEquipo.length)this.errorEquipo = 1;

            return this.errorEquipo;

        },
        cerrarModal() {
            this.modal = 0;
            this.tituloModal = '';
            this.eq_nombre = '';
            this.tipoAccion = 0;

        },
        abrirModal(modelo, accion, data = []) {
            switch(modelo){
                case "equipo": 
                {
                    switch(accion) {
                        case 'registrar': 
                        {
                            this.modal = 1;
                            this.tituloModal = 'Agregar equipos';
                            this.eq_nombre = '';
                            this.eq_descripcion = '';
                            this.id_categoria = 0;
                            this.eq_foto = '';
                            this.tipoAccion = 1;
                            break;

                        }
                        case 'actualizar': 
                        {
                            this.modal = 1;
                            this.tituloModal = 'Actualizar equipo';
                            this.tipoAccion = 2;
                            // en data = [] se recibe los registros
                            this.eq_id = data['id'];
                            this.eq_nombre = data['eq_nombre'];
                            this.eq_descripcion = data['eq_descripcion'];
                            this.id_categoria = data['id_categoria'];
                            this.eq_foto = data['eq_foto'];
                            break;
                            // console.log(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            this.selectCategoria();
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // llama a la funcion
        // le paso la pagina y lo que tengo en este momento en la variable buscar y campo
        this.listarEquipo(1, this.buscar, this.campo);
    }
```

Para mencionar un poco mas lo que quiero hacer es guardar el nombre de la imagen que el usuario va a subir y la imagen en si mover a la carpeta public de laravel.

esta es la funcion store de mi controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    if(!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
    $equipo = new Equipo();
    $equipo->eq_nombre = $request->eq_nombre;
    $equipo->eq_descripcion = $request->eq_descripcion;
    $equipo->id_categoria = $request->id_categoria;
    if(Input::hasFile('eq_foto')) {
        $file=Input::file('eq_foto');
        Image::make($request->file('eq_foto'))
            ->resize(144, 145)
            ->save(public_path().'/imagenes/equipos/' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $empresa->eq_foto=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    $equipo->eq_condicion = 1;
    $equipo->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $equipo->save();

}
```

No se si ya me salí un poco del tema de mi problema pero es que no puedo avanzar por este problema.

Comment: Para los input de tipo file no es correcto asignar un `v-model`, solo escuchar el evento `change` del control, seguro tiene un `v-model` asignado a un `input` de tipo file.

Comment: Puedes darme un ejemplo? si me dices así no lo entiendo muy bien

Comment: Hernan he añadido un respuesta, pero además creo que el código compartido del backend le quita claridad  al pregunta, ya que el error es del código Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La causa del error es básicamente porque  la entrada de tipo (file) archivo es de **solo lectura**, por lo cuál no se puede asignar un `v-model` y hacerse reactivo, por lo general se recomienda solo escuchar el evento `change` para obtener los archivos cargados en el `input`.

Para las referencias puede usar [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs), y para "escuchar" el evento change `@change`

```js
Vue.component('inputfile',{
 template :'<input type="file" @change="changeFiles" ref="miarchivo">',
 methods: {
    changeFiles(){
     //obtenemos los archivos
     // se pueden asignar a un array u objeto
     console.log(this.$refs.miarchivo.files);
    }
 }
});


new Vue({
  el :'#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<inputfile/>
</div>
```

Adicionalmente puede crear un componente dedicado para trabajar con  `v-model`, o recurrir a algunos que ya existen en la comunidad de `Vue`